# How to reduce the height of my div element, relative to the other div element

Tags: html, css, height

I am trying to reduce the height of my div element which contains content so that it is slightly     smaller than it's corresponding div so that the content does not overflow into other elements is their a method to executing this type of problem.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
   <script>
        .atlas.region-map
    {
    border: 2px solid #716E64;
    max-width: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    }

   .atlas .map-content .info-col
   {
    margin-left: 549px;
    width: 335px;
   }

  .atlas .map-content .info-col p
   {
   color: #5c5642;
   margin-top: 15px;
  font-size: 12px;
   }
  .Atlas_Test
  {
      height: 300px;
      font-size: 14px;
      overflow-y: scroll;
  }
  </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="info-col">
    <p>Content will go here</p>
    </div>

 </body>
```

Comment: put that CSS in style tag not in script tag Sir :)

Comment: http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html#.UuvTKNISU4c 

<div class="info-col"  => <div class="info-col clearfix"

Comment: Can you be more clear ? Maybe add full HTML ? I don't see anything wrong here http://jsfiddle.net/M8vbP/

Answer (score 0):

If that is not working, then it actually isn't executing!

You need to place CSS coding in `style` element not in `script`. Script element is for JS codes.

However, to lessen the size of the div you can try this code:

```
max-height: 90%; // shorten it!
```

This way you can stop the div from getting bigger than this size. And the content won't move out. Using this code, the element will get the 90% of the parent element's height size! Thus not moving out of the solution box.

To provide a scroll bar use:

```
overflow: scroll;
```